# Could someone please provide a ROS-ready raspberry pi filesystem?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've spent countless days trying to get ROS installed in my raspberry pi (running raspbian) so I could use it as an embedded system, and after so many dependency problems and manual system links, I sort of gave up.
There is a VM with ROS-indigo readily available for download, so couldn't someone provide a copy-paste filesystem for raspberry pi with ROS installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201774/could-someone-please-provide-a-ros-ready-raspberry-pi-filesystem?/) by [Jean-Luc Nacif Coelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/20055/jean-luc-nacif-coelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-01-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-01-26**:
Which ROS distro are you looking to use? I have hydro running on my pi, and I suppose I could create an image from it.

**Comment by [Jean-Luc Nacif Coelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/20055/jean-luc-nacif-coelho/) on 2015-01-26**:
That sounds great!
Would you please?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-01-27**:
I'll post an answer here with a link once I create the image, but that might not be until next week.

**Comment by [Jack2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/22001/jack2005/) on 2015-03-27**:
Dan did you get a chance to create that image? or if you have the instruction on how to build ROS on a raspberry PI would really appreciate it thanks

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-03-27**:
I don't think I'm going to have a chance to get an image put together anytime soon, but I can definitely get you a rosinstall file along with some instructions.

**Comment by [Jack2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/22001/jack2005/) on 2015-03-27**:
that would be great when do you think you can get me that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dlaz/aca2065fb2ff3cdb0eba/raw/a8d75fe052a2dd53a8793b7483c22d6604f9f8c1/pi.rosinstall) is a rosinstall file I created from the install on my pi. I was essentially able to follow the [hydro instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi).

Note that rosdep will complain about not being able to install python-rospkg, python-catkin-pkg, sbcl, and python-rosdep. Other than sbcl, which the instructions tell you how to deal with, the rest are installed with pip instead of apt.

You will also see

```
image_geometry: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
cv_bridge: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [debian]
```

Install opencv with `apt-get install libopencv-dev`

To silence the errors, add `--skip-keys "python-rospkg python-catkin-pkg python-rosdep opencv2"` to the rosdep call.

If you have any trouble, post a comment and I'll try to help.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-03-27**:
[Here](https://github.com/mars-uoit/ros_install_scripts/blob/master/install_ros_indigo_rpi.sh) is a script I used to install indigo on a few pis which is more or less the instructions stated above.